# Margins around a pdfpages produced document

Tags: margins, geometry, pdfpages

I have a beamer presentation I want to squeeze into a 2 in 1 A4paper document, but with margins around as beamer frames come against the up and down paper borders.

I tried unfortunatly this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2]{output.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and `output.tex` :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}               % thème
\usecolortheme{wolverine}       % variante de couleur
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First frame}
frame 1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Last frame}
frame 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\includepdf understands all graphicx keys, so you can use them to adjust the sizes. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,height=0.45\paperheight,frame,keepaspectratio,delta=0 10]{output.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bravo ! thank you.

Comment: @JohnKormylo it is a pdfpages key.

Comment: `\frame` is a beamer command opening a slide presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but information about the margin sizes (and how to exceed them).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}               % thème
\usecolortheme{wolverine}       % variante de couleur
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{First frame}
\rule{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Last frame}
\makebox[\textwidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{\textheight}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```